# StatelessSessionImpl in Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to test below method with Spring test 4.3.10 and Hibernate 5.2.12
But it always throw error at the transaction.commit();  line. That says:

ARJUNA022006: The ORB has not been initialized yet

```
public void insertSomethings(List<Thing> someThings)
{
    StatelessSession statelessSession = getStatelessSession();
    Transaction transaction = statelessSession.beginTransaction();

    for (Thing thing: someThings) {
        statelessSession.insert(someThings);
    }

    transaction.commit(); 
}
```

I check the code of StatelessSessionImpl.java in hibernate and this turn out a new line which does not exist in hibernate 4:

in beforeTransactionCompletion() it does nothing in previous Hibernate version. But, from  5.0, it is implemented and call flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(). In this flushBeforeTransactionCompletion() mehthod, I can see below code is always called to do:

```
boolean flush = false;
try {
    flush = (!isClosed()&& !isFlushModeNever()&&! JtaStatusHelper.isRollback(getJtaPlatform().getCurrentStatus());
}
```

So that, this fail my Unit test because we dont have JTA at this mode.

Does anyone face the same problem? Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to mark your test as @Transactional?

Comment: Yes I added and it does not help. There is the transaction manually open as above code. Problem is when it call commit(), the StatelessSessionImpl check JTA status. But, this is Unittest environment and there is no JTA platform.

Comment: Do you have configured Arjuna Transaction Manager as a Transaction manager in your configuration files? Because you can only use Arjuna inside a JBoss server.

If you are out of a JBoss server, you have to reconfigure Hibernate to use another transaction manager.

Comment: Hi Ildelian, I already configure it to use Jdbc transaction manager. Again. Problem is why DOES StatelessSession ALWAYS check JTA status. It is not there without Application server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this as adding NoJtaPlatfrom as jta configuration instead of using jdbc:

```
hibernate.transaction_factory=jta
hibernate.transaction.jta.platform=org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform
```